# Knockout + Bootstrap: Make collapsible detail rows in data table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

The scenario: An application that uses Knockout and Bootstrap to create a table of data. Each row of data will correspond to two rows in the table: a summary row and a detail row. The detail row shall be hidden until the user clicks or taps on the summary row. When the user clicks or taps on the summary row, show the detail row right underneath it. Optionally, if the user clicks or taps on the summary row and the detail row is already shown, collapse the detail row. Implement this without creating an observable for each row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap's [collapse functionality](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to implement this without creating an observable. Give the detail row an `id` attribute based on a unique identifier from the data. Then give the summary row a `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute and a Knockout-created `data-target` attribute pointing to the detail row.

The code below shows a pattern for the markup.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Enumeration">
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: { 'data-target': '#details'+ID }">
            <td>Summarize</td>
            <td>Some</td>
            <td>Info</td>
            <td>Here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse" data-bind="attr: { id: 'details'+ID }">
            <td colspan="4"><span data-bind="text: Details"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```